# How to create a contact list that can be imported into (almost) any device/program

Tags: email, import, contacts

My workplace has a lot of people coming and going and no-one keeps a central contact list. This leads to problems with getting in touch with people out-of-hours. Everyone uses different devices and software for managing contacts. Most common is iOS, OSX, gmail and Android with a little bit of Outlook.

What I want to do is send out an email to everyone with an attached file that they can import into their device/application of choice. It will just have names and mobile phone numbers - nothing else. Is there a standard format that I can do this with that I can easily generate myself?

Comment: [.csv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) should be pretty standard. Or move to a cloud hosted solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Funambol](http://www.funambol.com/) makes software which allows for contact and calendar syncing between different platforms. Not an exact answer to your question, but it will still allow you to achieve what you want.